# String.Format with SQL wildcard causing Dapper query to break

Tags: c#, sql, string-formatting, dapper

I'm having a bit of an odd problem with Dapper and string formatting. Here's the relevant code:

```
string end_wildcard = @"
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE (first_name LIKE CONCAT(@search_term, '%') OR last_name LIKE CONCAT(@search_term, '%'));";

string both_wildcards = @"
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE (first_name LIKE CONCAT('%', @search_term, '%') OR last_name LIKE CONCAT('%', @search_term, '%'));";

string formatted = @"
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE (first_name LIKE {0} OR last_name LIKE {0});";

string use_end_only = @"CONCAT(@search_term, '%')";
string use_both = @"CONCAT('%', @search_term, '%')";

// if true, slower query due to not being able to use indices, but will allow searching inside strings 
bool allow_start_wildcards = false; 

string query = String.Format(formatted, allow_start_wildcards ? use_both : use_end_only);
string term = "blah"; // the term the user searched for

// Using Dapper
db.Query(end_wildcard, new{ search_term = term}); // Works and returns results
db.Query(both_wildcards, new{ search_term = term}); // Works and returns results
db.Query(query, new{ search_term = term}); // Returns nothing
```

The first two queries, where the CONCAT statements with wildcards in them are baked into the string, work perfectly. However, if I take the CONCAT statements out and inject one or the other using String.Format, I get 0 results.

The oddest part of it is that I can debug it, grab the actual query string it uses, put it into MySQL and run it with a @search_term parameter set, and get results while it's paused. Let the code continue, and I get 0 results. Literally the only thing that is different is that one is a pre-compiled string, and the other uses String.Format.

Are '@' and '%' considered special characters by String.Format, or is something else I'm not seeing going on here? The formatted string is literally byte-for-byte equal to one of the two non-formatted strings, and again, pasting it into MySQL actually gives results from the formatted string. Dapper just seems to like two, and not the third, even when it's exactly equal to one of the first two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please indicate **exactly** what your `query` and `term` are in the example that is failing. I cannot reproduce any issue here. If I use the code as posted, `query` is identical to `end_wildcard`, and: it works fine. In a local test rig (with some invented data), I have:

```
connection.Query(end_wildcard, new { search_term = term }).Count().IsEqualTo(2);
connection.Query(both_wildcards, new { search_term = term }).Count().IsEqualTo(3);
connection.Query(query, new { search_term = term }).Count().IsEqualTo(2);
```

If you are seeing something different, I can only conclude that it must relate to your specific example.

But to be specific:

> Are '@' and '%' considered special characters by String.Format, or is something else I'm not seeing going on here?

Nope; `string.Format` only cares about things like `{n}` (for integer `n`), and `{{` / `}}` (which are escape sequences for `{` and `}` respectively).

Basically, I find it unlikely that dapper is doing anything related to this, but showing your exact `query` and `term`, *as they appear when it is failing* would help.

Comment: Well, this is odd. You're absolutely right. There was nothing wrong with it. Computer rebooted overnight, and this morning, everything's working perfectly. I think it was just one of those issues where VS gets corrupted somehow. Every couple of days, my Web API project decides it's missing a reference to SQLite, even though that's nowhere to be found in my project whatsoever.

Thanks for Dapper, by the way. It's awesome.

Comment: @Chris a new build went out earlier today BTW